# Conforming to a UITextField Delegate Using a CustomCell (subclass) textfield

Tags: swift, uitableview, delegates, textfield

I have a subclass, `CustomCell`, which inherits from my parent class, `CreateEvent`. The subclass describes the individual cells for the table view cell, which is on the `CreateEvent` View controller. In one specific cell, I have a textfield, that is linked to the `CustomCell` file, but I am having trouble getting the value from that textfield when a user enters into the textfield. I am also having trouble dismissing the keyboard with outside touches and pressing the return key, but I am primarily focused on getting the text from the textfield. I am familiar with doing these functionalities on ONE normal swift file but because this is a subclass and two swift files, I'm not sure what to do. This is my code:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var entranceFeeTextField: UITextField!

override func awakeFromNib() {
   super.awakeFromNib()

}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}
```

and

```
class CreateEventVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CustomCellDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let currentCellDescriptor = getCellDescriptorForIndexPath(indexPath)
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

// the following code describes the array for an expandable drop down 
if currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String == "idCellNormal" {
    if let primaryTitle = currentCellDescriptor["primaryTitle"] {
        cell.textLabel?.text = primaryTitle as? String
    }

    eventType = ((cellDescriptors[0] as! NSMutableArray)[0] as! NSDictionary)["primaryTitle"]! as! String
    if let secondaryTitle = currentCellDescriptor["secondaryTitle"] {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = secondaryTitle as? String
    }
}
else if currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String == "idCellTextfield" {
    cell.textField.placeholder = currentCellDescriptor["primaryTitle"] as? String
}


else if currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String == "idCellValuePicker" {
    cell.textLabel?.text = currentCellDescriptor["primaryTitle"] as? String
}

cell.delegate = self

return cell
}


func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField:UITextField) -> Bool {
entranceFeeAmount = cell.entranceFeeTextField.text!

return true;
}

}
```

My main question is that I am not sure how to set the textfield delegate, and how to properly conform to the delegate.

Comment: Are you creating the cells in a storyboard / NIB?

Comment: I am creating the specific cell that I am working with in a .xib file that contains the textfield

Comment: Will you have only one such cell, or do you intend to have more than one?

Answer (score 3):

Since only one specific cell contains a text field, in your custom cell's `awakeFromNib()`, check if the text field exists then set the delegate of the text field.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    if (self.entranceFeeTextField != nil) {
        self.entranceFeeTextField.delegate = self as UITextFieldDelegate
    }
}
```

You can pass the text from the text field to `CreateEvent` View controller using delegation.

To implement delegation, create a protocol at the top of your `CustomCell` class and add a method to transfer the string from `CustomCell` to `CreateEventVC`.

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate {
    func getTextFieldString(string: String)
}
```

Declare a delegate variable in your `CustomCell` class.

```
var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?
```

Trigger the protocol method in `textFieldDidEndEditing`:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    delegate?.getTextFieldString(string: self.entranceFeeTextField.text!)
}
```

Now, let `CreateEventVC` conform to the `CustomCellDelegate` protocol and implement `func getTextFieldString(string: String)` inside `CreateEventVC`.

```
func getTextFieldString(string: String) {
    print(string) //do whatever you want with it 
}
```

In `tableView(_, cellForRowAt:)`, remember to set `cell.delegate = self` because we want `CreateEventVC` to be the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what you want to achieve. You have set your delegate to be the cell, but want to update a property of the controller (`entranceFeeAmount`).

There are two ways of going at it. If you intend to have only one such cell, you can set the delegate to be your controller, rather than the cell itself. You can do that in `tableView(_, cellForRowAt:)`. That way, the controller will hear the text field's events, and handle them.

If you will have more than such cell, you will set the delegate in the cell's `awakeFromNib()`. That gets called when the cell is instantiated from the storyboard / NIB. The cell will be the delegate, rather than the controller, so you need to move that delegate method to the cell itself. However, now that each cell hears about its own text field, you need to notify the controller for each cell. This is a complex topic, and can be achieved using delegation, where the controller is a delegate of the cells.

Comment: I plan to have multiple cells in the tableview, but only one will have the textfield. You mentioned I need to set the delegate in the tableView(_, cellForRowAt:). Do you mean I should have cell.entranceFeeTextField.delegate = self, instead of cell.delegate = self
?

Comment: Yes. If only one cell with text field will exist, it would be best to have the controller the delegate of the text field.

Comment: After switching cell.delegate = self to cell.entranceFeeTextField.delegate = self, I got the error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when compiling

Comment: It seems `entranceFeeTextField` is nil. Did you connect that in your xib?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean. For the .xib, I have connected it to my CustomCell class. And I have connected an IBOutlet from the entranceFeeTextField to the CustomClass.

Comment: Well, something is not set up right. Right click on your text field and see if your property appears in that list.

Comment: Under referencing outlet it is connected to my CustomCell class. Perhaps I am not calling it correctly?